# Doctrine UniqueConstraintViolationException not caught/thrown in SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, exception, doctrine-orm

I have an SQLite table that contains data about images. One column is `position` which is a text field with where that image should be displayed on a site. That field has a unique constraint. Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE images (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, position TEXT UNIQUE
NOT NULL, caption TEXT, filename TEXT, album INTEGER NOT NULL, publicationDate TEXT, updated
TEXT, createdBy INTEGER
 NOT NULL, updatedBy INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (createdBy) REFERENCES users(id), FOREIGN KEY
(album) REFERENCES albums(id), FOREIGN KEY (updatedBy) REFERENCES users(id));
```

And, the relevant bits from the entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="images",indexes={
*       @Index(name="publication_date", columns={"publicationDate"})},
*       uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="unique_position", columns={"position", "fileName"})}
*       )
*/
class Image
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    **/
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
    */
    protected $position;
```

I can successfully write to the table (Doctrine persist, then flush) unless there is a unique constraint violation on the `position` column. When there is a unique constraint violation, flush() silently fails (no write to the DB) and the application continues to execute. Here is the relevant code - after setting up and persisting the entity:

```
        try {
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $message['type'] = 'alert-info';
            $message['content'] = "$title added succesfully";
            return $message;
        } catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
            $message['type'] = 'alert-danger';
            $message['content'] = "$title could not be added " . $e;
            return $this->create($message, $formVars);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message['type'] = 'alert-danger';
            $message['content'] = "$title could not be added " . $e;
            return $this->create($message, $formVars);
        }
```

Why am I not catching the exception? Or, is it not thrown at all?

Comment: Since the application continues to execute then the exception is not thrown at all

Comment: have you tried without try catch if it throws the exception at all?

Comment: @B0re Yes. I am pretty sure that the exception is not thrown. Rain's comment above seems to concur

Comment: To be honest I'd take a different approach and use @UniqueEntity symfony constraint on the field "positon", validate the entity with ValidatorComponent and then based on the result flush or create the catch alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my hint provided above with code implementation just run it 2 times to see the result, here is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\TestEntity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="test")
     */
    public function test(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $newEntity = new TestEntity();
        $newEntity->setPosition('test');

        // In addition $form->isValid() does this for you and displays form error specified in entity
        if(($result = $validator->validate($newEntity))->count() === 0) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($newEntity);
            $em->flush();
            dump('Entity persisted');
        } else {
            dump($result); // <- array of violations
            dump('Sorry entity with this position exists');
        }

        die;
    }
}
```

and here is your entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="test_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestEntityRepository")
 * 
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields={"position"},
 *  errorPath="position",
 *  message="Duplicate of position {{ value }}."
 * )
 */
class TestEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="string", length=190, unique=true) // key length limit for Mysql
     */
    private $position;

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Out of curiosity I tested your first idea and it seems to work for me

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\TestEntity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="test")
     */
    public function test(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $newEntity = new TestEntity();
        $newEntity->setPosition('test');

        try {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($newEntity);
            $em->flush();
        } catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
            dump('First catch');
            dump($e);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e) {
            dump('Second catch');
            dump($e);
        }

        die;
    }
}
```

It results in the dump of 'First catch', but this might have something to do with that I'm using mysql not SQlite, also here's a reference to [Symfony Validation Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) in case you want to check it out
**EDIT2**
Simple Validator class

```
class SomeSortOfValidator
{
    public function exists($entity, $fieldName, $fieldValue)
    {
        // Lets suppose you have entity manager autowired.
        $record = $this->em->getRepository($entity)->findOneBy([
            $fieldName => $fieldValue
        ]);
        return $record ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point me to info on how to build the validator object? Your example controller has a parameter - ValidatorInterface $validator

Comment: this is autowired by symfony it is provided by symfony/validator bundle

Comment: ahh. I am not using Symfony - I'll have to see if I can create an instance and provide it from my container.

Comment: Easy way to implement such validator with doctrine only would be to create function which takes entity, fieldName, and  fieldValue, I editted my answer for you